# Django authentication from iOS client

Tags: ios, django

What is the best way to get an iOS client to login to a Django application - I've explored 2 methods below but each seems to have its pros and cons.

On the client side I am using AFNetworking - but open to using NSURLsession as well if it simplifies the authentication process.

(A) **Using inbuilt session variables in Django** 
Client sends login credentials to get a session key and uses this key in all headers during an active session.

Can I use the @login_required directive in Django to automatically do this or do I need to manually code the session variable check (e.g. compare the incoming session key with request.session.session_key)? In addition can I still use tastypie (though Django is directly doing the authentication) as an API wrapper or will I have to use Django for data (JSON) handling

(B) **Using OAuth2 in tastypie (+Django)**
Create a client ID and secret key for a user; client sends this out at the beginning of a session (along with username and pasword) - following this tastypie manages the session

It seems like this needs a client ID and a secret key that needs to be generated for each user. It's straightforward to generate this from the Django admin panel but I'm not clear on how to create this dynamically and pass it onto the client as soon as a user has been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tastypie there's a management command to generate API keys to the users that doesn't have one:

```
python manage.py backfill_api_keys
```

Also you'll need a method to autogenerate an API key for each new user, [from Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from tastypie.models import create_api_key

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
```

Once all the clients have the API key you can use BasicAuthentication to get the access token to use in your app. [Check this gist](https://gist.github.com/mkubenka/5142319), and then you can make a request to `http://example.com/api/token/auth/` to get your token.

Check out [this post for an iOS example using OAuth2](http://blog.ingenuity.ph/2013/08/connecting-ios-app-to-django-tastypie.html)

Comment: Thank fasouto. In the OAuth2 example you point to, the app seems to be hardcoded with the client ID and key - hopefully all users can use the same ID/key pair?

Comment: I think that yes, they can be the same. Anyway I'm not 100% sure.